# Smartsheet API Bulk Update Multiple Sheets

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

I have had a lot of success with the SS REST API. I am currently trying to perfect the "Work at Scale" component of a few of my integrations. As the subject suggests I am trying to figure out if it is possible to construct a single JSON payload that will update multiple sheets with one call. I can construct the payload for a single sheet and then loop through a list of those sheets. However, with the potential of needing to update thousands of sheets the aforementioned functionality would drastically improve my processing time. Any suggestions? Does a comprehensive list of "Bulk Operations" exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to hear of your success so far. But no, there is no way to update more than one sheet in a single call. You *can* update multiple rows in a sheet with a single call.